# How to make a div fill the entire page height using css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to extend the bottom of the middle section of the webpage(div main) down the whole page, covering up the background at the bottom.

Here is the and image of the webpage and CSS code file for the webpage:

[image: Webpage Image]

```
body {
    background: url('black_gradient.png')repeat-x;
    text-align: center;
}
#main {
    width: 1000px;
    background: url('brown gradient.jpg')repeat-x;
    margin: 25px auto;  
    border: solid 2px #ff3819;
    border-bottom: solid 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family:"Times New Roman";
    font: 24pt;
    color: #000000;
}
hr {
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
p {
    font-family:"Calibri";
    font-size: 12pt;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 48px;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `#main {min-height: 100vh}`. The vh unit is 1% of the viewport (window) height.

Comment: This worked! Thank you!

Comment: I did, but thank you for the tip! I am new here.  Also do you know how to make fonts in HTML cursive?

Comment: Find a web page with the style of font you like and use your browser's *inspect element* to view the values of css properties such as `font-style` and `font-family`.

Comment: AWESOME! Never new this!  So the CSS is under the styles tab?

Comment: Be aware when using vieport-height (vh) and viewport-width (vw) units because some browsers still don't support them.

Answer (score 2):

Just a sidenote, but vh doesn't always get along with every browser.  I've had issues with it in IE in particular.  If that is important to you, you can also use these rules:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! I will try this out as well!

Comment: this is one of the best answers